# want to execute a java script code .cs page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a change password popup window.i want to send the user name and changed password to the parent window after it has been successfully changed by the popup window and want the popup to be closed after few seconds....but i am not able to call the javascript from the .cs file.i am giving the code..can u help me how to do it...`

```
string script = "<script>" + "return updateParent();";
         if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("someKey"))
         {
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "someKey", script);
         }   

<script type="text/javascript">
       function updateParent() {
           opener.document.form1.getElementById(Username).value = document.form1.getElementById(Username).value;
           opener.document.form1.getElementById(pswrd).value = document.form1.getElementById(new_paswrd).value;
           self.close();
           return false;
       }
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
string script = "<script>" + "return updateParent();";
```

to this

```
string script = "<script>" + "return updateParent();" + "</script>";
```

:)